# Как сделать «динамический» padding?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Учусь верстать...
Сделал блок, в нем расположил элементы, блоку задал padding.

Проблема в том, что когда я в dev-tools меняю ширину окна, на определенном моменте картинки начинают "вылазить" вправо, а потом и вовсе уходят за экран.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, эту проблему можно решить медиазапросами, но они как-бы жёстко задают padding.
Мне хотелось бы, чтобы при уменьшении ширины окна, когда контент не помещался в рамки контейнера, то контент либо наезжал на padding, либо padding уменьшался.

[Вот](https://codepen.io/Drovosek/pen/MqxONW) пример кода:

```css
.main__work {
 padding: 100px 179px;
 background-color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
}
.work__title {
 font-size: 44px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 300;
}
.work__text {
 color: #6c6c6c;
 font-style: italic;
 margin-top: 56px;
}
.work__works {
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 175px;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
 grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
 grid-row-gap: 30px;
 grid-column-gap: 30px;
 justify-items: center;
 width: 1142px;
}
.line {
 height: 4px;
 background-color: #fcac45;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.short-line {
 width: 99px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="main__work">
 <h2 class="work__title">Take a look at <b>our works</b></h2>
 <div class="line short-line"></div>
 <p class="work__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus ex quidem maiores ullam quis, at asperiores minus ad eaque maxime possimus cum ab iusto assumenda velit excepturi porro ipsa tenetur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus ex quidem maiores ullam quis, at asperiores minus ad eaque maxime possimus cum ab iusto assumenda velit excepturi porro ipsa tenetur.</p>
 <div class="work__works">
 <img class="work1" src="https://i.postimg.cc/fVddh36q/work1.png" alt="our work">
 <img class="work1" src="https://i.postimg.cc/fVddh36q/work1.png" alt="our work">
 <img class="work1" src="https://i.postimg.cc/fVddh36q/work1.png" alt="our work">
 <img class="work1" src="https://i.postimg.cc/fVddh36q/work1.png" alt="our work">

 <img class="work2" src="https://i.postimg.cc/kVFtB0Mx/work2.png" alt="our work">
 <img class="work2" src="https://i.postimg.cc/kVFtB0Mx/work2.png" alt="our work">
 <img class="work2" src="https://i.postimg.cc/kVFtB0Mx/work2.png" alt="our work">
 <img class="work2" src="https://i.postimg.cc/kVFtB0Mx/work2.png" alt="our work">
 
 <img class="work3" src="https://i.postimg.cc/XGjBFsXt/work3.png" alt="our work">
 <img class="work3" src="https://i.postimg.cc/XGjBFsXt/work3.png" alt="our work">
 <img class="work3" src="https://i.postimg.cc/XGjBFsXt/work3.png" alt="our work">
 <img class="work3" src="https://i.postimg.cc/XGjBFsXt/work3.png" alt="our work">
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: @Никита-Фаст, то есть вы предлагаете всё, что находится в .main__work обернуть в еще один div, например div.container, контейнеру задать строгую ширину и margin: auto ?
Мне такой подход известен, но смущает 2 подряд идущих контейнера.

Comment: @НикитаФаст, тогда получается я не понял вашу идею. Можете показать как вы собирались использовать тут margin для решения поставленного вопроса?

Comment: я grid не использую так как он плохо поддерживается, голову не заморачию себе тем что не работает , есть flexbox который работает на 100%

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/NLJyQa?editors=1100  и заметьте ни одного медиазапроса не было

Comment: @НикитаФаст, хм... оригинальный способ. Но как быть если у нас несколько таких блоков и у них не белый фон? https://codepen.io/Drovosek/pen/BObrwY

Comment: @НикитаФаст, белый margin между body и контейнером https://i.paste.pics/33a415e0dc0930ff9e34bfa24280bae5.png

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83489/discussion-between---and--).